# automatically added junk in Angular api call

Tags: angular, postman

when API call then automatically added "%E2%80%8B" in API URL.
Here example
BaseUrl%E2%80%8B/ControllName%E2%80%8B/MethodName

Comment: Please explain your question and add some code if you can. Because here your format isn't a question at all and so we don't understand what do you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this happening when copying URLs from a word document or other document editors. You try coping URL to notepad and remove any unwanted spaces/characters and copy the URL from notepad.